# WAMP wrong Physical Path

Tags: http, wamp, wampserver, windows-server-2012

I have first installed my WAMP Server on my personnal PC. It worked fine.
Then I pluged that PC in a network of a company (25 PC in total). I had acces to all there network. And I managed to make it work and accessible to everyone in the company but the WAMP is still on my computer.

To resolve that little problem, they got a Server with Windows Server 2012 installed. So I wanted to install my WAMP + DB, on this server.

So I installed correctly WAMP and MySql but when I go to the url that I put exactly the same on my personal PC, it shows me an error like : `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

Like if the WAMP wasn't launched but I'm sure it is launched correctly.

Can this be a firewall issue ? Like an service bloking the port 80 (I guess ?).
Sorry but the network isn't my best subject.

**EDIT**

I found from where my error comes.
When I go to my url 10.13.48.60:80/my_page.php
In my error message, I see `Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\`
but thats wrong, it should just be `Physical Path      C:\WAMP\www\`

How can I change that ?

Comment: You have IIS installed on the new server. That will have grabbed port 80 before you get to start WAMPServer ( icon is probably Orange !!! ). So if you are not using IIS on this new server, uninstall it.

Comment: Yes thats what I did (2 weeks ago) ^^  but thx anw for the answer xD

Comment: Well then you could have either updated your answer or answered your own question and saved me the time.

Comment: Sorry mate, I never taught that someone would answer me actually but I will next timen, I won't forget.